# Filtering HTML embedded text with RegEx in random order and only keep keywords between certain tags

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a large list of supplier provided HTML and I want to rewrite their descriptions. In the HTML I only want to keep certain keyfeatures. Everything else I want gone.

I used this regex, which works fine if it is found in exactly this order.

```
.*<span><strong>Material:</strong> (.*?)</span>(.*)<span><strong>Size:</strong> (.*?)</span>(.*)<span><strong>Weight:</strong> (.*?)</span>.*\n
```

But unfortunately it isn't. Is there a way to randomize this search so it will keep each of these regardless of the order it is found?

I echo it in Notepadd++ for now, like this:

```
$1 $3 $5\n
```

I appreciate any hint in the right direction. I tried with "|" seperators and grouped matches but it just made the code greedy.

Comment: Can you expand your question with some lines of the input, together with needed output. (also put in the 'out of order' thing). I do not know if this can be done in Notepad++, but maybe I do know another tool... 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with named capture groups associated with lookahead:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?=.*?<span><strong>Material:</strong>(?<m>.*?)</span>)(?=.*?<span><strong>Size:</strong>(?<s>.*?)</span>)(?=.*?<span><strong>Weight:</strong>(?<w>.*?)</span>).*$`
- Replace with: `$+{m} $+{s} $+{w}`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                                       # beginning of line
  (?=                                   # start lookahead
    .*?                                 # 0 or more any character but newline
    <span><strong>Material:</strong>    # literally
    (?<m>.*?)                           # named capture group (m), 0 or more any character but newline
    </span>                             # literally
  )                                     # end lookahead

  The explanation is the same for the 2 other named capture group (s) and (w)
  (?=.*?<span><strong>Size:</strong>(?<s>.*?)</span>)
  (?=.*?<span><strong>Weight:</strong>(?<w>.*?)</span>)

  .*                                    # 0 or more any character but newline
$                                       # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$+{m}           # content of named capture group m
$+{s}           # content of named capture group s
$+{w}           # content of named capture group w
```

**Given:**

```
blah<span><strong>Material:</strong>mat_name</span>blah<span><strong>Size:</strong>size</span>blah<span><strong>Weight:</strong>weight</span>blah

blah<span><strong>Size:</strong>size</span>blah<span><strong>Weight:</strong>weight</span>blah<span><strong>Material:</strong>mat_name</span>blah
```

**Result for given example:**

```
mat_name size weight

mat_name size weight
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Fantastic. Works like a charm, only Added \n like this to keep the new lines:
$+{m} $+{s} $+{w}\n

Comment: @KimK.: Right, glad it helps.